# Application rejected, crashing after launch issue

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-tv

I have uploaded application for android TV so many times but still rejected that application. the reason is "your application crashed when attempting to purchase 'gas.'", but in our case we checked our side like add email in developer account --> account details --> "License Testing" and also check real time purchase like add credit card/debit card so it working perfectly fine, so I don't know what is the reason behind that, so is there any why like we give access to google as a tester? or any other way? so please give me solution

[this is the error that exact showing google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pxGQ.png)

I have tried in our side like we check payment part in as a tester and also tried real time test like we add credit/debit card

Comment: I suggest you to upload your apk on firebase robo test and check if crashes there usually google has bots set up to test the apps uploaded so test your apk with firebase is a good option

Comment: @Mr.Patel this firebase robo test is only for android mobile not for android TV Firebase robo test showing me error like "this application not have main launcher activity" because I am using LEANBACK LAUNCHER activity for android TV

Comment: @Anshu Patel did you have find the solution of this problem? Share please

Comment: Hi did you have any solution? getting same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Please add this in your manifest file.

In your launcher activity add the following intent filter.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

also your manifest file must have this tag.

```
 <uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />
```

These are necessary steps for Android tv apps, otherwise your app is not recognized as a tv app and  Google won't accept.

Comment: mine was also rejected several times. Can you share you manifest file?